# Successfully Write A File In Nexus, But Failed In Xiaomi And ZTE Phone

Tags: android

I have this Android manifest :

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2"></uses-feature>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

and I have this MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button_jepret;
    ImageView image_preview;
    static final int CAM_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button_jepret = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_jepret);
        image_preview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_preview);

        button_jepret.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {

                Intent camera_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File file = getFile();

                camera_intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
                startActivityForResult(camera_intent, CAM_REQUEST);

            }
        });
    }

    private File getFile() {

        File folder = new File("sdcard/camera_app");

        if (!folder.exists()) {
            folder.mkdir();
        }

        File image_file = new File(folder, "gambar_01.jpg");

        return image_file;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        String path = "sdcard/camera_app/gambar_01.jpg";
        image_preview.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path));

    }
}
```

this app works on Nexus 4 phone, but I tried on Xiaomi and ZTE phone it ends with this error message :

```
02-08 10:11:15.883 6159-6259/com.example.camera.camera E/HAL: hw_get_module_by_class: module name gralloc
02-08 10:11:15.883 6159-6259/com.example.camera.camera E/HAL: hw_get_module_by_class: module name gralloc

02-08 10:11:29.886 6159-6159/com.example.camera.camera E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: sdcard/camera_app/gambar_01.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

it seems that this app failed to store the image captured by camera into the storage. but why in Nexus phone works?

thank you.

Comment: Are the OS version the same? Xiaomi by default uses Mi OS instead of Android OS, hence the structure maybe slightly different.

Comment: @Raptor : my Nexus phone is Lollypop, Xiaomi is Marshmallow and ZTE is KitKat

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous loopholes in the code. First you should always check the return parameter of `folder.mkdir()` in order to check if the file was successfully created or not.

Now from the code, looks like you wanna dump all your image files into a folder called `camera_app` in external storage. Physically where the external storage resides on an Android device differs from device to device. So instead of hardcoding the path, use the API `context.getExternalFilesDir()` and check if it is available.

Also if you are coding this on Android 7.0 or up, you should give a look at this as to how android suggests you to organise your content on external storage - https://developer.android.com/training/articles/scoped-directory-access.html